# Why did some Klingon faces change while others did not?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9

In the *Star Trek: The Original Series*, we see Klingons for the first time. They have faces similar to that of humans. In later appearances on other *Star Trek* shows, their faces have ridges. Now, I'm not asking why their faces change; that is addressed in *Enterprise*. What I'm asking is why some changed while others do not. For example, the character of Karnas' appearance for the most part does not change from *The Original Series* to *The Next Generation*. However, the military leader Koloth has his appearance change from *The Original Series* to *Deep Space Nine*, which takes place around the same time as *The Next Generation.* Why is this? Both in- and out-of universe answers are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Karnas](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Karnas) was not Klingon he was a Mordanite.

[Michael Pataki](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Michael_Pataki), the actor who played Karnas, also played [Korax](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Korax) in The Trouble with Tibbles.